# Passing an array within a structure in CUDAfy

Tags: c#, cuda, marshalling, cuda.net, cudafy.net

Using VS 2012, .NET 4.5, 64bit and CUDAfy 1.12 and I have the following proof of concept

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Cudafy;
using Cudafy.Host;
using Cudafy.Translator;

namespace Test
{
[Cudafy(eCudafyType.Struct)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ChildStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public float[] FArray;
    public long FArrayLength;
}

[Cudafy(eCudafyType.Struct)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ParentStruct
{
    public ChildStruct Child;
}

public class Program
{
    [Cudafy]
    public static void KernelFunction(GThread gThread, ParentStruct parent)
    {
        long length = parent.Child.FArrayLength;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var module = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(
          ePlatform.x64, eArchitecture.sm_35,
          new[] {typeof(ChildStruct), typeof(ParentStruct), typeof(Program)});
        var dev = CudafyHost.GetDevice();
        dev.LoadModule(module);

        float[] hostFloat = new float[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < hostFloat.Length; i++) { hostFloat[i] = i; }

        ParentStruct parent = new ParentStruct
        {
            Child = new ChildStruct
            {
                FArray = dev.Allocate(hostFloat),
                FArrayLength = hostFloat.Length
            }
        };

        dev.Launch(1, 1, KernelFunction, parent);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

When the program runs, I am getting the following error on the dev.Launch:

`Type 'Test.ParentStruct' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.`

If I remove the float array from the ChildStruct, it works as expected.

Having worked in C/C++/Cli and CUDA C in the past, I am aware of the nature of the error. Some solutions to this error suggest setting the struct size manually using `Size` parameter of `MarshalAs`, but this is not possible due to the variety of types within the struct.

I looked at the generated .cu file and it is generating the float array as a `float *` which is what I expected.

**Is there a way to pass an array within a struct to the Kernel? And if there isn't what is the best second alternative?** This problem doesn't exist in CUDA C and it only exists because we are marshaling from CLR.

Comment: Does this also mean that List<struct> would not be possible with CUDAFY?

Comment: First, it needs to be an array that you are sending, not a list. However, I don't think this is a problem unless if your struct has an array.

Comment: ok cool. The struct only contains datetime, string decimal etc. I have a feeling the decimal might be an issue though as i didnt see it mentioned in the "CUDA by example". + 1 on ur comment and question btw ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent good time reading the source code of CUDAfy to see if there is a solution to this problem.

CUDAfy is trying to make things too simple for .NET developers and shield them away from the `IntPtr` and other pointer concepts. However, the level of abstraction makes it very hard to think of an answer to this problem without a major refactor to the way this library works.

Not being able to send a float array within a struct is a show stopper. I ended up doing PInvoke to the CUDA Runtime and not using CUDAfy.

Comment: Or you could of sent psuedo ptr through another array, as a C# and C++/ASM dev. I've used it quite often, IMO c# integration now days requires such solutions; decoupled memory management.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of .NET, not CUDAfy. Data must be blittable and a non-fixed size array is not. This is valid and based on the CUDAfy unit tests on codeplex:

```
[Cudafy]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=64, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public unsafe struct PrimitiveStruct
{
    public fixed sbyte Message[32];
    public fixed char MessageChars[16];
}
```

There is also no reason to store the array length explicitly since you can use the Length property within device code.

Comment: I have seen this code, however, it is dealing with fixed size arrays and the problem is with variable size arrays.

Comment: Just set a max size, and null out the rest