# CUDAFY, how to get arrays inside structs

Tags: c#, cuda, cudafy.net

How can you have a struct full of arrays in cudafy?

This appears a somewhat trivial issue, but I could not find an easy implementation of it on the net.

Some links suggest it cannot be done, see for example: [Passing an array within a structure in CUDAfy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340278/passing-an-array-within-a-structure-in-cudafy)

While others suggest it can be done through a somewhat lengthy helper function, see for example http://cudafy.codeplex.com/discussions/283527

I am looking to pass a single struct into my Cudafy kernel, where for example the struct looks like...

```
    [Cudafy]
    public struct myStructTwo
    {
        public float[] value_x;
        public float[] value_y;
        public float[] value_z;
    }


    public struct myStructTwo
    {
        public IntPtr value_x;
        public IntPtr value_y;
        public IntPtr value_z;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been addressed in a [Codeplex answer](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/discussions/538310). It looks to be possible using a fixed size e.g.

> ```
> [Cudafy]
> public struct myStructTwo
> {
>     public float value_x[size];
> }
> ```

I will let this question remain open in case further responses are received.

Comment: structs need to have a fixed total size. this is what allows them to be handled by eg. arrays as values and not pointers. i guess you could use a list, since the struct just stores a pointer to the list

Comment: @RasmusDamgaardNielsen surely the question here is trying to determine whether a struct with an array can be passed to the GPU, so a pointer to a list wouldn't work?